# MapboxGL JS - Display 3d buildings in lower zoom level

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I use **MapboxGL JS v2** with `mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11` style.
And I use this code to display **3D buildings** on my map:

```
map.addLayer({
    'id': '3d-buildings',
    'source': 'composite',
    'source-layer': 'building',
    'filter': ['==', 'extrude', 'true'],
    'type': 'fill-extrusion',
    'minzoom': 15,
    'paint': {
        'fill-extrusion-color': '#666',
        'fill-extrusion-height': ['interpolate', ['linear'], ['zoom'], 15, 0, 15.05, ['get', 'height']],
        'fill-extrusion-base': ['interpolate', ['linear'], ['zoom'], 15, 0, 15.05, ['get', 'min_height']],
        'fill-extrusion-opacity': 0.9,
    }
});
```

It's working as expected, as seen in [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/).

Now, what I want is to load these buildings at lower zoom level, for example **10** instead of **15**.
So, I changed `minzoom` from `15` to `10`, and I also changed the `interpolate` stuff to use linear interpolation from `10` to `15.05`.

Here is the final code:

```
map.addLayer({
    'id': '3d-buildings',
    'source': 'composite',
    'source-layer': 'building',
    'filter': ['==', 'extrude', 'true'],
    'type': 'fill-extrusion',
    'minzoom': 10,
    'paint': {
        'fill-extrusion-color': '#666',
        'fill-extrusion-height': ['interpolate', ['linear'], ['zoom'], 10, 0, 15.05, ['get', 'height']],
        'fill-extrusion-base': ['interpolate', ['linear'], ['zoom'], 10, 0, 15.05, ['get', 'min_height']],
        'fill-extrusion-opacity': 0.9,
    }
});
```

Unfortunately it's not working, it looks like it still waits for zoom level 15 to load, and I didn't find anything on the internet to make it work.

Comment: Just a quick note here, did u update the zoom value in ```new mapboxgl.Map({
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
        center: [-74.0066, 40.7135],
        zoom: 10, //<----here
        pitch: 45,
        bearing: -17.6,
        container: 'map',
        antialias: true
    });``` while creating new instance of mapboxgl map?

Comment: @Dolly Yes, but as it represents the `initial zoom level`, scrolling with the mouse to zoom also works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like tile set's for building are generated after zoom level 13.

*[READ HERE](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-tiling-service/examples/building-footprints/)*

So, when we query `map queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ["3d-buildings"] });` on zoom level below 13 no feature's get added on Map. But once the zoom level is greater then 13 few building feature's get added.

Screenshot zoom level<13

[image]

Screenshot zoom level>13

[image]

*UPDATE*

In order to make it work from zoom level 10 to 15, You have to create your own tileset using [Tilesets CLI](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-tiling-service/examples/building-footprints/#using-the-tilesets-cli-to-generate-a-tileset) where you have to make a recipe json and have to provide zoom levels like:

```
{
   "version": 1,
   "layers": {
   "building_footprints": {
   "source": "mapbox://tileset-source/username/building-footprints",
   "minzoom": 10, //<---
   "maxzoom": 15
   }
 }
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

[Step by Step Creation](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/get-started-mts-and-tilesets-cli/)

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the information, so, are you saying there is no solution to get buildings for example at zoom level 10?

Comment: Seems like it @Marc

Comment: Do you think I could achieve my goal using another source (not the one provided by Mapbox) ?

Comment: @Marc Read Here https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-tiling-service/examples/building-footprints/#using-the-tilesets-cli-to-generate-a-tileset  by default building feature's are available from 13 to15 zoom level but you want them on lower zoom level, you have to publish your own tilesets through mapbox studio. I haven't done this bymyself but seems like it will work.